# Rails Simpleform setting the width of a form input element

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms, html-table, simple-form

I'm using the gem simpleform inside a table

I want to adjust the width of each form element of the simple form can I do that?

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work

```
    <td><%= listing.name %></td>
<td><%= f.input :suite, :input_html => { :size => 10, :maxlength => 10 } %></td>
```

I looked at the simpleform documentation here but couldn't find how to specifically set the width. Here is what my form inside a table looks like. I'd like to make the columns narrower.

[image]

As you can see the column widths are very wide. Please advise how to make them the appropriate size so they don't take too much space.

Comment: That should work. Maybe only use `:size`? See https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/168

Comment: nope. This: <td><%= f.input :suite, :size => 10} %></td>        didnt work either

Comment: Try setting in CSS? And check colimn widths. Are you using a grid system?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear.  I wanted you to try `<td><%= f.input :suite, :input_html => { :size => 10} %></td>`.  On second thought, that shouldn't really make a difference.  Maybe there is something in your CSS that is overriding it?

Answer (score 17):

I've used `<%= f.input :fieldname, :input_html => {:maxlength =>2,:style=> 'width: 20px'}%>` with success. Are you suppressing all labels? (via `:label=>false`)?