# Simple_form inputs are too long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

As always with Ruby on Rails I use simple_form gem to handle forms in more elegant and, well, simple way. But i have this problem, that string inputs are not generated properly. i mean they work as they are supposed to, but they are just extremely long, like totally out of my screen. it isn't normal behaviour is it? should i apply any special css for this? or maybe there is some other solution?

This form i have looks like this:

```
= simple_form_for @book, url: books_path, method: :post do |f|
    = f.input :title, label: false, placeholder: "title"
    = f.input :author, label: false, placeholder: "author"
    = f.input :isbn, label: false, placeholder: "ISBN"
    = f.input :publishing_date, label: false, placeholder: "Publishing date"
    = f.input :amount, label: false, placeholder: "Amount"
    = f.submit class: "btn btn-success"
```

Other that this i just put 'gem "simple_form"' to the Gemfile and thats it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good answer I found from typing simple_form width:

{:maxlength =>2,:style=> 'width: 20px'}%>

from this answer:

[Rails Simpleform setting the width of a form input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025074/rails-simpleform-setting-the-width-of-a-form-input-element)